# How to execute function sequentially or synchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, promise

I have 4 function which I want to execute in sequence.

Particularly the 4th function should only execute only when all 3 previous functions are complete.

I tried using call backs but for sure I am not using it correctly. How do I make it sequential.

I heard about `then` function in JavaScript but looks like it only works with `ECMAScript 6` (not sure), but when I try using it in my script gets an undefined error.

```js
function longRunningFunction(callBack) {

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#div1').html('Div1 Done');
  }, 5000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#div2').html('Div2 Done');
  }, 5000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#div3').html('Div3 Done');
  }, 5000);

  callBack();

}
longRunningFunction(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#div4').html('But changes 1st!');
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
#div4 {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}

#div1 {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div4">
  My content should be changes at last!
</div>
<div id="div1">
  Div1
</div>
<div id="div2">
  Div2
</div>
<div id="div3">
  Div3
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want `Div2 Done` to occur 5000ms after `Div1 Done`?

Comment: Put `callback()` at the end of the last `setTimeout()`. I'd also suggest using the queue instead of timeouts, as it gives you more extensible control.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, No. I just want callBack to happen after all 3 functions finishes.

Comment: What error did you get when trying `then`? Promises are the best solution for your scenario, so it's better to figure out if you're using them incorrectly rather than dream up a less reliable alternative.

Comment: "*looks like it only works with ECMAScript 6*" - would that be a problem?

Comment: @Bergi, I have an idea it's supported by modern browsers. But when I run the application , with .then() getting  'then()' is not defined.

Comment: @Simsons Promises are supported natively in all contemporary browsers. But they don't come magically, you will need to explicitly create a promise (or call a function that does so) to use its `.then()` method.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, looking at the documentation now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Promises` to achieve that.
Set a promise for each async change that will take place and wait for them to be done with [`Promise#all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) :

```
Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]).then(() => {
  callBack();
});
```

***Demo:***

```js
function longRunningFunction(callBack) {

  let p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#div1').html('Div1 Done');
      resolve();
    }, 5000);
  });

  let p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#div2').html('Div2 Done');
      resolve();
    }, 5000);
  });

  let p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#div3').html('Div3 Done');
      resolve();
    }, 5000);
  });

  Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]).then(() => {
    callBack();
  });
}
longRunningFunction(function() {
    $('#div4').html('But changes 1st!');
});
```

```css
#div4 {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}

#div1 {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div4">
  My content should be changes at last!
</div>
<div id="div1">
  Div1
</div>
<div id="div2">
  Div2
</div>
<div id="div3">
  Div3
</div>
```

Comment: The timeouts were just a delay the OP was using to try to better ensure that all 3 finish before the 4th. So you could remove those in your answer.

Comment: Should we call longRunningFunction instead of callBack? Div4 does not change!

Comment: @Simsons I made a typo in the `Promise#all` call. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

You have x4 functions about setTimeout, so you can combine simple function whit promise and async/await functionality:

Just replace `() => console.log()` with `() => $('#div1').html('Div1 Done');`

```js
function sequentialTimeout(time, func){
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(func()), time));
}

async function sequence(){
  await sequentialTimeout(500, () => console.log('1'))
  await sequentialTimeout(500, () => console.log('2'))
  await sequentialTimeout(500, () => console.log('3'))
  sequentialTimeout(500, () => console.log('4'))
}

sequence()
```

Comment: Don't pass a callback. Just use `then` instead if you absolutely need one. Your approach also fails at catching errors from the `func()` call.

Comment: @Bergi I think 1 depth callback is a good approach. Why do you think the opposite? 2. I haven't added reject for simplicity sake.

Comment: If you are using `await`, no callback at all should be needed; and still if you want to use one then it should be a promise `then` callback. No, you didn't just miss a `reject` (where would you do that, and why, after a timeout?), you are not catching exceptions from `func`. Using `then` would automatically do that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Promises, as another answer has said. But if you think that is too much "heavy machinery" for such a simple use-case (which it arguably is), you can just set a flag for each successful timeout, and then fire the callback when all are set. The following is one way:

```
function longRunningFunction(callBack) {

  var done = [false, false, false];

  function checkIfDone(cb) {
    if (done[0] && done[1] && done[2]) {
      cb();
    }
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#div1').html('Div1 Done');
    done[0] = true;
    checkIfDone(callBack);
  }, 5000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#div2').html('Div2 Done');
    done[1] = true;
    checkIfDone(callBack);
  }, 5000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#div3').html('Div3 Done');
    done[2] = true;
    checkIfDone(callBack);
  }, 5000);
}
longRunningFunction(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#div4').html('But changes 1st!');
  }, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score -3):

You can try generators

```js
function* generateSequence() {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  return 3;
}

let generator = generateSequence();

let one = generator.next();

alert(JSON.stringify(one)); // {value: 1, done: false}
```

Comment: Generators (alone) don't help with making asynchronous code sequential.